# Bind flag enums to a control and back to the enum property

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, ivalueconverter

I've a telerik RadAutoCompleteBox to show / select enum flags and a converter for the binding. But it works only to bind to the target not back to the property. The ConvertBack method just isn't called.

WPF:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox x:Name="RadAutoCompleteBox" FilteringBehavior="{StaticResource EmptyTextFilteringBehavior}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:EnumBindingSource {x:Type model:FlagEnum}}}" SelectedItems="{Binding Entity.FlagEnum, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ListToFlagEnumConverter}}" />
```

Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        if (typeof(Enum).IsInstanceOfType(value))
        {
            string concatenatedEnum = ((Enum)value).ToString();
            ObservableCollection<Enum> enumList = new ObservableCollection<Enum>();
            foreach (string item in concatenatedEnum.Split(','))
            {
                enumList.Add((Enum)Enum.Parse(type, item));
            }
            return enumList;
        }
    }
    return Binding.DoNothing;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    ObservableCollection<Enum> enumList = (ObservableCollection<Enum>)value;
    string enumString = String.Join<object>(",", enumList);
    return Enum.Parse(targetType, enumString);
}
```

Edit: What i tried so far

- Use SelectedItem[TowWay] and SelectedItems[OneWay]: Now ConvertBack gets called, but no lists will be excepted and the enum input isn't showed properly.
- SelectedItem[TowWay] and SelectedItems[TowWay]: ConvertBack gets called and failed (conversion exception is thrown but target type is the right type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a Blend Behavior. All the converter logic is done there and i have more possibilities.

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behavior:EnumFlagsBehavior EnumValue="{Binding CommunicationSystemEntity.TlsVersion, Mode=TwoWay}" NoneValue="{x:Static model:TlsVersion.None}" AllValue="{x:Static model:TlsVersion.All}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```